# Sqlite database exception: file is encrypted or is not a database in blackberry?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I am working on a firm application in which I need to create a local database on my device.

I create my local database through create statement[ **It works well**]

Then I use that file and perform insert operation through fire-fox sqlite plugin, I need to insert aprox 2000 rows at a time so I can not use code. I just run insert manually through sqlite plugin in fir-fox.

After that I just use that file in my place of my local database.

When I run select query through my code, It show Exception:java.lang.Exception: Exception: In create or prepare statement in DBnet.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseException: SELECT distinct productline FROM T_Electrical ORDER BY productline: **file is encrypted or is not a database**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem, I was doing a silly mistake by creating a file manually by right click in my RES folder, that is not correct. We need to create the database completely from SQlite plugin, then it will work fine. "Create data base from SQLITE(FIle too) and perform insertion operation from SQLITE, then it will work fine"

This is very rare problem, but i think it might be helpful for someone like me....!:)

Comment: Good, you should now accept your own answer to complete the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should check to see if there is a version problem between the SQLite used by your Firefox installation and that on the BlackBerry. I think I had the same error when I tried to build a database file with SQLite version 2.

You also shouldn't need to create the database file on the device. To create large tables I use a Ubuntu machine and the sqlite3 command line. Create the file, create the tables, insert the data and build indexes. Then I just copy the file onto the device in the proper directory.

Comment: Hello Richard, I got this once in my last application, where I did the same task. Here in this application when I run on my simulator it works fine, but on device its creating problem. I have 0.7.7 version of sqlite plugin in fir-fox.  Please let me know If I can do anything with the current conditions.

Comment: I am continuously working on this issue, just got a little good news that, my application is working on the simulator but not on device. My requirement are: To create a database with create query in my code than use that database file and insert 2500 rows at a time through sqlite plugin in firefox than use that updated file as a database in my application. I keep that file in RES and transfer that to SD card on applicaiton installation. It works fine before the use of sqlite plugin of firefox. please suggest me something.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a simple thing. One password was set to that db. I just used it and prolem got solved.